# Using a variable inside an included file from function

Tags: php, function, variables, include

I'd like to have a header.php file throughout my site.  I currently have the following:

header.php

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php if(isset($depth)){echo $depth;};?>css/style.css">
```

functions.php

```
function include_layout_template($template="", $depth="")
{
    global $depth;
    include(SITE_ROOT.DS.'public'.DS.'layouts'.DS.$template);
}
```

index.php

```
<?php include_layout_template('header.php', "../"); ?>
```

But $depth dissappears, I can't even echo $depth; its just blank.  How can I get the depth variable for use in header.php?

Comment: $depth is both a global variable and a parameter to the function `include_layout_template`? that must be messing things up...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to rename depth variable in function call

```
function include_layout_template($template="", $my_depth="")
{
   global $depth;
   //if need $depth = $mydepth
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `$depth` variable is disappearing, because it is passed as parameter first but then defined to use the global parameter.

I will explain with an example:

```
$global = "../../"; //the variable outside
function include_layout_template($template="", $depth="")
{
    global $depth; //This will NEVER be the parameter passed to the function
    include(SITE_ROOT.DS.'public'.DS.'layouts'.DS.$template);
}
include_layout_template("header.php", "../");
```

To solve, simply modify the function parameter other than the depth itself.

```
function include_layout_template($template="", $cDepth="") { }
```